# Adding button in runtime using button onclick event

Tags: java, android

I'm making a game in where the platform will add new button in each level the user has cleared. but I cant add new xml tag in the project on runtime. I'm a little lost of what to use or how to implement.

```
    run = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRunChallengeMode);

    run.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent newForm = new Intent(Form2.this,Form2.class);
            buttonPanel = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearButtonPanel);
            Button newButton = new Button(null);
            newButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            newButton.setId(a);
            newButton.setText("Button " + a);
            buttonPanel.addView(newButton);
            a++;
            startActivity(newForm);


        }
    });
```

below is the xml code

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/buttonPanelChallengeMode"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/IDE"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/LinearButtonPanel">


    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because after adding the button to the layout you are starting the new Activity no matter it's the same activity. Whenever activity is created it will always use the initial xml format. I think you are under the impression that adding new button will persist and becomes a part of XML. That's not true, if you want to start the new activity. Set new Button value in Bundle, then in onCreate check the existence of bundle. If exist's then add a new button.

```
int buttonId = -1;
protected void onCreate(Bundle b){
     //set the layout related stuff first
     Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
     if(b!= null && (b.getInt(NEW_BUTTON_KEY, -1)!=-1)){
        buttonPanel = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearButtonPanel);
        for(int i = 0; i< b.getInt(NEW_BUTTON_KEY, -1); i++) 
        Button newButton = new Button(this);
        newButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        newButton.setId(i);
        newButton.setText("Button " + i);
        buttonPanel.addView(newButton);

     }
}
```

By the way why are you making new activity? Just add the button in the same activity, otherwise your activity stack will become massic with every level.

Comment: In on click listener send the value of 'a'

Answer (score 0):

```
Button newButton = new Button(null);
```

You give to the context null, i suggest you to give proper context. Also you can set tag for button with `newButton.setTag(value)`

Answer (score 0):

Your Code  is not true
you create a button and add to a LinearLayout and after that you call startActivity for load an Activity. So You reset the LinearLayout and buttons clear from that.

you should :

```
run = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRunChallengeMode);

run.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent newForm = new Intent(Form2.this,Form2.class);

        newForm.putExtra("a", a);

        startActivity(newForm);


    }
});
```

and in the create , get Extras :

```
String a = getIntent().getIntExtra("a");
```

now you can create the button.